# How do python references work? Why do lists share modifications done to other references while integers don't?

Tags: python, reference, immutability, mutability

The following snippet:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a
b.append(6)

print(a)
print(b)
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

so when modifying `b`, we also modify the list accessible through `a`.

However, with integers, this snippet:

```
a = 1
b = a
b +=1

print(a)
print(b)
```

prints

```
1
2
```

So here, `a` and `b` seem to not reference the same thing? Why is the value of `a` not 2 in the second snippet?

Comment: Because `int` is a primitive and `list` is not?

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Give the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) a full read some day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, everything is an object. Everything is a *name* for an *address* (pointer) per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

On that page you can scroll down and find the following:

> Numeric objects are immutable; once created their value never changes

Under that you'll see the `int` type defined, so it makes perfect sense your second example works.

On the top of the same page, you'll find the following:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value. An object’s identity never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the object’s address in memory.

Python behaves just like C and Java in that you cannot reassign where the pointer to a name points. Python, like Java, is also pass-by-value and doesn't have a pass-by-reference semantic.

Looking at your first example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x7ffdc64cd420'
>>> b = a + 1
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x7ffdc64cd440'
>>> print(a)
1
>>> print(b)
2
```

Here it is shown that the operation `b = a + 1` leaves `a` at `1` and `b` is now `2`. That's because `int` is immutable, names that point to the value `1` will always point to the same address:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 1
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x7ffdc64cd420'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x7ffdc64cd440'
>>> hex(id(c))
'0x7ffdc64cd420'
```

Now this only holds true for the values of `-5` to `256` in the [C implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong), so beyond that you get new addresses, but the mutability shown above holds. I've shown you the sharing of memory addresses for a reason. On the same page you'll find the following:

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed. E.g., after a = 1; b = 1, a and b may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the implementation, but after c = []; d = [], c and d are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists. (Note that c = d = [] assigns the same object to both c and d.)

So your example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x17292e1cbc8'
>>> b = a
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x17292e1cbc8'
```

I should be able to stop right here, its obvious that both `a` and `b` refer to the same object in memory at address `0x17292e1cbc8`. Thats because the above is like saying:

```
# Lets assume that `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is 0x17292e1cbc8 in memory
>>> a = 0x17292e1cbc8
>>> b = a
>>> print(b)
'0x17292e1cbc8'
```

Long and skinny? You're simply assigning a pointer to a new name, but both names point to the same object in memory! **Note:** This is *not* the same as a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) because no external compound object is made.

Comment: *"Everything is a name for an address"* -- Do you mean every *variable* is a name for an address? Not everything has a name of course, like for example literals like `0`.