# (Beginner) Why does the temporary variable change in example 1, but not in example 2?

Tags: python-3.x

These are the two examples, could someone help me by explaining?

Example 1

```
v1=list(range(5))
v1temp=v1
v2=1

def ext(x,y):
    return x.append(y)

ext(v1,v2)
print(v1temp)
```

Example 2

```
a=1
b=2
atemp=a
a=b
print(atemp)
```

Comment: `list` is a mutable object while `int` is not. There is no method similar to `.append()` for `int`s.

Comment: This question is a more direct duplicate, asking about Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206114/how-reference-works-in-python-integer-vs-list-in-list-both-value-are-same-why