# How do Assignment Operators and Lists Work? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer, assignment-operator

The assignment operator appears to work differently for lists than it does for integers:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> newlist1 = list1
>>> print(id(list1))
140282759536448
>>> print(id(newlist1))
140282759536448
>>> newlist1.append(6)
>>> print(id(newlist1))
140282759536448
>>> print(list1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print(newlist1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The Assignment Operator works in a similar way with integers:

```
>>> int1 = 1
>>> newint1 = int1
>>> print(id(int1))
140282988331248
>>> print(id(newint1))
140282988331248
```

But modifying one of the integers creates a new ID:

```
>>> newint1 = newint1 + 1
>>> print(id(newint1))
140282988331280
>>> print(id(int1))
140282988331248
```

Why does modifying a list not create a new ID?

As well, how would you create a new ID for a list?

Comment: Well, you modify the list, but you replace the integer.

Comment: your attribut is just a name, so you can affect the same reference to two names. If you want to create a new list you can copy the first one by adding `[:]`. Integers (str and some others) are treated diffently to optimize time and space memory. You can find more information in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206114/how-reference-works-in-python-integer-vs-list-in-list-both-value-are-same-why

Answer (score 0):

You should use `newlist1 = list1.copy()` because when you do `newlist1 = list1` you are not creating new list you are referencing the same list

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you assign a list to a new variable, you will only pass the address of the list to it.
That is why the `id()`function return the same value.

If you want to actually copy the list you have to use the `copy()` function:

```py
initList = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(id(initList))

copiedList = initList.copy()
print(id(copiedList))
```