# Why did the variable change in the first case and not in the second?

Tags: python

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9]
lst2 = lst1
lst2.append(789)
print(lst1, lst2, sep='\n')

a = 100
c = a
c += 1
print(a)
```

Is it because the list is the global variable or what?

Comment: In the second case your printing (a) not (c). (c) is 101. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Looks like `c = a` does not to what you think it does. [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531087)

Comment: Oh, you're trying to update the value of a by updating the value of c?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do python references work? Why do lists share modifications done to other references while integers don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206114/how-reference-works-in-python-integer-vs-list-in-list-both-value-are-same-why)

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Answer: `list` is mutable and `int` is not

### mutable `list`

In the given code, both `lst1` and `lst2` refer to the same list object initially. When you assign `lst1` to `lst2` (`lst2 = lst1`), you are not creating a new list. Instead, you are creating a new reference `lst2` that points to the same list object as `lst1`. Therefore, any modifications made to the list through `lst2` will be reflected when accessing the list through `lst1`, and vice versa.

In the first case, when you append the value 789 to `lst2`, it modifies the underlying list object. Since both `lst1` and `lst2` point to the same list, you will see the updated list when printing both `lst1` and `lst2`.

```py
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9]
lst2 = lst1
lst2.append(789)
print(lst1, lst2, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9, 789]
[1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9, 789]
```

### immutable `int`

Regarding the `int` value, integers are immutable in Python, which means their values cannot be changed once they are assigned. In the code snippet, when you assign the value of `a` to `c` (`c = a`), you are creating a new reference `c` that points to the same integer object as `a`. However, when you perform `c += 1`, you are not modifying the integer object itself. Instead, you are creating a new integer object (101) and reassigning it to the reference `c`. This does not affect the original value of `a`.

```py
a = 100
c = a
c += 1
print(a)
```

Output:

```
100
```

### copy()

If you want your `lst2` to be independent, then use `copy()`

```py
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9]
lst2 = lst1.copy()
lst2.append(789)
print(lst1, lst2, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 14, 33, 1, 9, 789]
```

But in case you list contains multi-level mutable objects, then `copy()` will act strange too. Because `copy()` only makes the copy of the first level. And the other mutable objects' reference stays the same.

```py
lst1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]] # list inside a list
lst2 = lst1.copy()

lst2[2][0] = 33 # updating the first value of the inner list

print(lst1, lst2, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [33, 4]]
[1, 2, [33, 4]]
```

As you can see, it changed the first list too.

## deepcopy()

To copy you list including all of its contents, you can use the `deepcopy()` function from the copy module. `deepcopy()` creates a new object with a completely independent copy of the original, including all nested objects.

```py
from copy import deepcopy


lst1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]]
lst2 = deepcopy(lst1)

lst2[2][0] = 33

print(lst1, lst2, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
[1, 2, [33, 4]]
```

Here, `lst2` is completely independent from `lst1`. So the value of `lst1` stayed the same.